# Expand/Collapse GridView rows of the same type

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row

I have a gridview with some boundfields and templatefields.  My data are sales Unit-Price-Store, right now the user selects a store (from a DropDownList) and the Grid is all Unit-Price for that store.

Is there a way to make put a button next to each unit so that when the user clicks it, that row expands to include a new row for each store?  IE, when I'm looking at Store 1 and I click the button I also get to see Unit-Price info for Stores 2,3,4 (but just for this item)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery.  Basically, I tagged that column and then did an each statement.  If value.innerHTML != Store $(this).closest('tr').hide();  Else assign it a function on click that looks at all 'tr' where Unit matches but Store doesn't and slideToggle()